# Calibre error: 'QWebEngineProfile' object has no attribute 'setUrlRequestInterceptor', how do fix it? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center, calibre

```
calibre, version 4.99.4 (linux, embedded-python: False)
Conversion error: Failed: Convert book 1 of 1 (Unity in Action, Third Edition)

Convert book 1 of 1 (Unity in Action, Third Edition)
Conversion options changed from defaults:
  read_metadata_from_opf: '/tmp/calibre_4.99.4_tmp_4y7oebgy/w0m37zz2.opf'
  output_profile: 'generic_eink'
  verbose: 2
  cover: '/tmp/calibre_4.99.4_tmp_4y7oebgy/l9x_gys7.jpeg'
  pdf_sans_family: 'Nimbus Sans [urw]'
  pdf_serif_family: 'Nimbus Roman [urw]'
  pdf_mono_family: 'Nimbus Mono PS [urw]'
Resolved conversion options
calibre version: 4.99.4
{'asciiize': False,
 'author_sort': None,
 'authors': None,
 'base_font_size': 0.0,
 'book_producer': None,
 'change_justification': 'original',
 'chapter': "//*[((name()='h1' or name()='h2') and re:test(., "
            "'\\s*((chapter|book|section|part)\\s+)|((prolog|prologue|epilogue)(\\s+|$))', "
            "'i')) or @class = 'chapter']",
 'chapter_mark': 'pagebreak',
 'comments': None,
 'cover': '/tmp/calibre_4.99.4_tmp_4y7oebgy/l9x_gys7.jpeg',
 'custom_size': None,
 'debug_pipeline': None,
 'dehyphenate': True,
 'delete_blank_paragraphs': True,
 'disable_font_rescaling': False,
 'duplicate_links_in_toc': False,
 'embed_all_fonts': False,
 'embed_font_family': None,
 'enable_heuristics': False,
 'expand_css': False,
 'extra_css': None,
 'filter_css': '',
 'fix_indents': True,
 'font_size_mapping': None,
 'format_scene_breaks': True,
 'html_unwrap_factor': 0.4,
 'input_encoding': None,
 'input_profile': <calibre.customize.profiles.InputProfile object at 0x7f46ee96dca0>,
 'insert_blank_line': False,
 'insert_blank_line_size': 0.5,
 'insert_metadata': False,
 'isbn': None,
 'italicize_common_cases': True,
 'keep_ligatures': False,
 'language': None,
 'level1_toc': None,
 'level2_toc': None,
 'level3_toc': None,
 'line_height': 0.0,
 'linearize_tables': False,
 'margin_bottom': 5.0,
 'margin_left': 5.0,
 'margin_right': 5.0,
 'margin_top': 5.0,
 'markup_chapter_headings': True,
 'max_toc_links': 50,
 'minimum_line_height': 120.0,
 'no_chapters_in_toc': False,
 'no_inline_navbars': False,
 'output_profile': <calibre.customize.profiles.GenericEink object at 0x7f46ee96dfa0>,
 'page_breaks_before': '/',
 'paper_size': 'letter',
 'pdf_add_toc': False,
 'pdf_default_font_size': 20,
 'pdf_footer_template': None,
 'pdf_header_template': None,
 'pdf_hyphenate': False,
 'pdf_mark_links': False,
 'pdf_mono_family': 'Nimbus Mono PS [urw]',
 'pdf_mono_font_size': 16,
 'pdf_odd_even_offset': 0.0,
 'pdf_page_margin_bottom': 72.0,
 'pdf_page_margin_left': 72.0,
 'pdf_page_margin_right': 72.0,
 'pdf_page_margin_top': 72.0,
 'pdf_page_number_map': None,
 'pdf_page_numbers': False,
 'pdf_sans_family': 'Nimbus Sans [urw]',
 'pdf_serif_family': 'Nimbus Roman [urw]',
 'pdf_standard_font': 'serif',
 'pdf_use_document_margins': False,
 'prefer_metadata_cover': False,
 'preserve_cover_aspect_ratio': False,
 'pretty_print': False,
 'pubdate': None,
 'publisher': None,
 'rating': None,
 'read_metadata_from_opf': '/tmp/calibre_4.99.4_tmp_4y7oebgy/w0m37zz2.opf',
 'remove_fake_margins': True,
 'remove_first_image': False,
 'remove_paragraph_spacing': False,
 'remove_paragraph_spacing_indent_size': 1.5,
 'renumber_headings': True,
 'replace_scene_breaks': '',
 'search_replace': '[]',
 'series': None,
 'series_index': None,
 'smarten_punctuation': False,
 'sr1_replace': None,
 'sr1_search': None,
 'sr2_replace': None,
 'sr2_search': None,
 'sr3_replace': None,
 'sr3_search': None,
 'start_reading_at': None,
 'subset_embedded_fonts': False,
 'tags': None,
 'timestamp': None,
 'title': None,
 'title_sort': None,
 'toc_filter': None,
 'toc_threshold': 6,
 'toc_title': None,
 'transform_css_rules': '[]',
 'uncompressed_pdf': False,
 'unit': 'inch',
 'unsmarten_punctuation': False,
 'unwrap_lines': True,
 'use_auto_toc': False,
 'use_profile_size': False,
 'verbose': 2}
InputFormatPlugin: EPUB Input running
on /tmp/calibre_4.99.4_tmp_4y7oebgy/f3rk07k6.epub
Found HTML cover OEBPS/default_cover.xhtml
Parsing all content...
Parsing OEBPS/C04.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/APP_A.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/FM.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/IBC.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/titlepage.xhtml ...
Parsing OEBPS/C07.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/APP_B.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/P1.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C011.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/praise.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C08.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/APP_C.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C01.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C012.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/title.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C09.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/P2.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/APP_D.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C02.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C013.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/copyright.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/P3.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C05.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/default_cover.xhtml ...
Parsing OEBPS/UnityinAction3eIX.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C03.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/AFTER.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/Hocking3_TOC.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/C010.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/Styles/Style01.css ...
Parsing OEBPS/C06.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/IFC.htm ...
Parsing OEBPS/Styles/Style00.css ...
Referenced file 'Text/C012.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/APP_C.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C013.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C06.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/P1.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/APP_A.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C011.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C02.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/FM.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/AFTER.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/P3.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/P2.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C04.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C09.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C01.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C07.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/APP_B.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C03.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C05.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/UnityinAction3eIX.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/APP_D.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C08.htm' not found
Referenced file 'Text/C010.htm' not found
Reading TOC from NCX...
Merging user specified metadata...
Detecting structure...
    Detected chapter: Part 1 First steps
    Detected chapter: Part 2 Getting comfortable
    Detected chapter: Part 3 Strong finish
Flattening CSS and remapping font sizes...
Source base font size is 12.00000pt
Removing fake margins...
Found 30 items of level: div_1
Found 2871 items of level: p_2
Found 78 items of level: div_2
Found 147 items of level: p_5
Found 312 items of level: p_4
Found 1572 items of level: p_3
div_1  left margin stats: Counter({'': 24})
div_1  right margin stats: Counter({'': 24})
Negative text indent detected at level  p_2, ignoring this level
div_2  left margin stats: Counter({'0': 32, '': 23})
div_2  right margin stats: Counter({'0': 32, '': 23})
p_5  left margin stats: Counter({'0': 147})
p_5  right margin stats: Counter({'30px': 111, '0': 36})
p_4  left margin stats: Counter({'0': 312})
p_4  right margin stats: Counter({'0': 312})
Negative text indent detected at level  p_3, ignoring this level
Cleaning up manifest...
Trimming unused files from manifest...
Trimming 'OEBPS/Images/default_cover.jpeg' from manifest
Trimming 'OEBPS/default_cover.xhtml' from manifest
Creating PDF Output...
Converting input as a text based book...
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/calibre-parallel", line 20, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/ipc/worker.py", line 215, in main
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/convert/gui_conversion.py", line 41, in gui_convert_override
    gui_convert(input, output, recommendations, notification=notification,
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/convert/gui_conversion.py", line 28, in gui_convert
    plumber.run()
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plumber.py", line 1274, in run
    self.output_plugin.convert(self.oeb, self.output, self.input_plugin,
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plugins/pdf_output.py", line 188, in convert
    self.convert_text(oeb_book)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plugins/pdf_output.py", line 253, in convert_text
    convert(
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/pdf/html_writer.py", line 1195, in convert
    manager = RenderManager(opts, log, container.root)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/pdf/html_writer.py", line 279, in __init__
    ans.setUrlRequestInterceptor(self.interceptor)
AttributeError: 'QWebEngineProfile' object has no attribute 'setUrlRequestInterceptor'
```

I downloaded from Software Centre and also tried installing from command line for Ubuntu 20.04 but I get the same error.
It was working fine on my Ubuntu installation on the other SSD but not with this new installation on this newer SSD.
I saw this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=944875
It says it should have been fixed.
What should I do?
When I uninstalled, I followed these instructions:  https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-/calibre?type=uninstall
I ran after installing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 6):

As advised here: https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux
Download from there, do not use versions elsewhere as they are buggy or outdated.